# Domain Redirect

Tags: redirect, dns

I have domain for ex. **example.com**. That domain blocked in malaysia. So i am planning to redirect **example.com** to **example.my** only for malaysian user. I know how to redirect domain using `php, javascript` etc, those are server and client level, but i dont know how to do it in *domain* level. My domain is registered on name.com, but it seems they dont have feature to redirect domain by country. is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) to see if the incoming request is originating from Malaysia and then redirect accordingly.

Comment: I afraid this is not working because when a government is blocking a site by DNS. The traffics never reach the hosting server. Therefore, a geolocation such as http://lite.ip2location.com is not effective to resolve this blocking issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recommend all visitors to use public DNS instead of local ISP DNS which has blacklisted your site example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the country wise access by blocking the IP range of that company fro the control panel or from the server.